# Computer Graphics error in Code Block Compiler

Tags: c, bgi

I am using Code Blocks compiler for my Computer Graphics pogramming in C. While building the following program, I am getting this error:" graphics.h: no such file or directory"- While as the same program easily runs on Turbo C/C++ Compiler.
Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<conio.h>

#include<graphics.h>


void boundary_fill(int x, int y, int fcolor, int bcolor)

{

    if ((getpixel(x, y) != fcolor) && (getpixel(x, y) != bcolor)) {
    putpixel(x, y, fcolor);
    boundary_fill(x + 1, y, fcolor, bcolor);
    boundary_fill(x - 1, y, fcolor, bcolor);
    boundary_fill(x, y - 1, fcolor, bcolor);
    boundary_fill(x, y + 1, fcolor, bcolor);
    boundary_fill(x + 1, y - 1, fcolor, bcolor);
    boundary_fill(x + 1, y + 1, fcolor, bcolor);
    boundary_fill(x - 1, y - 1, fcolor, bcolor);
    boundary_fill(x - 1, y + 1, fcolor, bcolor);
    }
}


 void main()

  {

    int x, y, fcolor, bcolor;

    clrscr();
    printf("Enter the seed point (x,y) : ");
    scanf("%d%d", &x, &y);
    printf("Enter boundary color : ");
    scanf("%d", &bcolor);
    printf("Enter new color : ");
    scanf("%d", &fcolor);

    int gd = DETECT, gm = DETECT;
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, "");
    cleardevice();

    /*
       please ceate your own shapes
       to make a closed area.
     */

    boundary_fill(x, y, fcolor, bcolor);

    getch();
  }
```

Comment: You should be using the preview function for your Computer Graphics questions.

Comment: the error message indicates the graphics.h file is not present in the local directory not in the system include directory.  If the file exists, you have a choice of either copying it to a 'known' location or adding the path to the file via (for GCC) '-Ipathto graphics.h' in the compile statement.